# Pexpect carriage return issue

Tags: python, bash, pexpect

I have create one application that uses pexpect to retrieve output of some commands
One of the example of commands that i do is the following:

```
ps aux
```

And this is a bit of the output directly from pexpect

```
root 28039 0.0 0.1 57780 3056 ? Ss Sep26 0:04 /opt/services/s^M
root 28093 0.5 0.4 131688 6492 ? Ss Sep26 93:25 /opt/services/s^M
root 28125 0.2 0.8 222680 13012 ? Ssl Sep26 36:21 /opt/services/s^M
```

The problem here is that output is truncated and not only added the '\r' in the middle of the output.
This might be solved using "| cat" in the command, but i need a solution that do not involve redirecting the output to cat.

I have seen this happen when i send a big command but the output is always the command with the ^M in the middle.

Is there any change that i can do in the terminal or in pexpect in order to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you please show the code?

Comment: The code is very complicated at this point with a bunch of classes and stuff. But what i place here is what i see when i activate the output in pexpect to the screen

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
ps axuww
```

The `ww` means

```
   w               Wide output. Use this option twice for unlimited width.
```

---

```
import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn('ps auxww')
while True:
    try:
        child.expect('\r\n')
        print(child.before)
    except pexpect.EOF:
        break
```

Comment: The problem doesnt seem to be the ps itself but the fact that the console cuts the output in smaller chunks using '\r' this looks like something related to pexpect itself

Comment: @jpereira : ps may well be detecting that it's running in a terminal, and trying to nicely format its output to the terminal width. The `ww` option will stop it doing that. You could also make the terminal wider using the [setwinsize() method](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/pexpect.html#pexpect.spawn.setwinsize).

Comment: @ThomasK : yes i solved the issue by changing the terminal size

Answer (score 0):

as discussed in comments, the `ps aux` command is truncating its output due to the implicit terminal width setting. You can prevent this by telling ps to use wide output (the `ww` in `ps auxww`) or increasing the terminal width (pexpect `setwinsize()`) as discussed in the comments.

The `^M` in the output is your UNIX-like operating system displaying the DOS-style CR/LF line endings. This is because pexpect actually operates a psuedo-TTY device. Something explained in the pexect [documentation](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#find-the-end-of-line-cr-lf-conventions)

> The best way to match the end of a line is to look for the newline: `"\r\n"` (CR/LF). Yes, that does appear to be DOS-style. It may surprise some UNIX people to learn that terminal TTY device drivers (dumb, vt100, ANSI, xterm, etc.) all use the CR/LF combination to signify the end of line. Pexpect uses a Pseudo-TTY device to talk to the child application, so when the child app prints `"\n"` you actually see `"\r\n"`.